# Why aren't my getters and setters working for title but they are working fine for description?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a todo list and i've got a 'createBasicTodo' factory function that is being invoked in my standard 'createTodo' function. I'm trying to restructure this to use getters/setters in some places. In the below code, the getters and setters aren't working for the createBasicTodo (being invoked from createTodo) but they are working for the description property in the todo. I can't figure out why this is. What am I doing wrong?

```
// basic todo functionality for parent & child todos
export const createBasicTodo = ({ title, priority = 'medium' }) => {
  if (!title) return throwError('Give your Todo a title!');

  console.log(title);

  let todoTitle = validateString(title);
  console.log(todoTitle);
  
  return {
    get title() {
      console.log('getting title');
      return todoTitle;
    },
    set title(newVal) {
      console.log('setting title');
      const validatedTitle = validateString(newVal);
      if (validatedTitle) {
        todoTitle = validatedTitle
      } else {
        throwError("please enter a valid title!");
      }
    },
    priority: priorityProperty(priority),
    isComplete: completionProperty(),
  };
}

// parent todo built off basicTodo using composition
export const createTodo = ({ title, description = '', priority = "medium", dueDate = null }) => {
  let todoPriority = priority;
  let todoDueDate = dueDate;
  let basicTodo = createBasicTodo({ title, priority });

  console.log(basicTodo);

  return {
    ...basicTodo,
    get description() {
      console.log('getting description');
      return description;
    },
    set description(newVal) {
      console.log('setting description');
      description = newVal;
    },
    checklist: checklistProperty(createBasicTodo),
    dueDate: dateProperty(dueDate),
  }
}
```

I am expecting to see the `console.logs` when I view or change the test todo's title. I'm not seeing them and am able to set the title to invalid values.

Comment: Your spread in the createTodo evaluates the title from the basicTodo but does not copy the getter/setter.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know that the spread operator doesn't copy accessors. I ended up using the copying accessors function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#examples